# How to determine RSquared using a fitted Probability density function?

Tags: regression, forecasting, r-squared

I am testing 7 probability density functions for best fit on solar radiation data for the island of Trinidad. One of the statistical parameters i must use for testing best fit is the coefficient of determination ($R^2$). I have used histograms to represent the actual measured data.

For $R^2$ I am using the formula:

$R^2= 1 - \frac{(sum of(MeasuredVals - EstimatedVals))}{(sum of(MeasuredVals -    
           MeanOfMeasuredVals))]}$

I am having difficulty understanding how to determine the Estimated Values that go with the measured values. I am using the MATLAB `'distribution fitter'` app and EasyFitXL for fitting. I believe I have to use the inverse cumulative distribution function but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you're new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Please check your formula, it is not correct (see this wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)). Also, part of the question is not clear. For example, what is the model you are estimating?

Comment: Why do you think you have to use $R^2$ to assess this? (Or, I suppose, four years later, why did you think that?)

Answer (score 1):

For reasons related to the issue you've encountered, $R^2$ doesn't seem like an appropriate way to measure how well a sample agrees with a proposed PDF. Instead, you might look at the likelihood, or the earth mover's distance from the empirical CDF.